# A bad day at mathexchange ...

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, best-practices

OK, first I must apologize if this title or this meta place is inappropriate, but I'm unaware of a better place to post this.

Today I had an unpleasant day at math.stackexchange.

For starters, I got IMHO undeserved downvotes.
When I assumed that those are the people suggesting to change things and commented, I was wrong.  Nobody knows who downvoted and they did not comment.
That is not against the rules, but I did not like it.

Also I met many bugs. I just got white pages with gibberish and insults on it, without even a menu bar or anything that shows this is mathexchange.

Hacks, viruses, I dunno. But I got a "whoops something went wrong" page from math.stackexchange window after it often.

Also, I was blocked a few times because the site was "overcrowded" and had to log in again and search again where I was.

Also, I don't get the idea that I'm banned, or was that an error too?
I mean, I did not remove questions or answers, I have a positive reputation and even medals (or badges).

So apparently people appreciate what I post.
That does not make sense to me.

I'm considering closing my account while I should not be.

I'm not a happy user.

And I don't know where to find a good alternative for stackexchange, but that seems insufficient to stay.

I'm considering giving up math on the net.

I feel controlled and insulted.  Although I got a positive reputation, that's really air to me if I'm banned, not taken seriously or insulted.

I'm not in the mood to cheat to get a lot of reputation and I'm not willing to risk the effort to spends years building reputation to just risk getting banned later.

I have a life too.

An unhappy user.

Comment: I have never heard of anyone having the kind of problems you describe. Please do join the math chatroom, where people may be able to help you find what the problem was, as Rob suggests. In any case, *abandoning math on the net* for a bad day on some random site is probably making too much of it! We all have bad days on- and off-line :-)

Comment: **Hint:** If you want to be taken seriously, try using *proper* English. "ppl" is not a word. If you wrote all this post from a cellphone, kudos, but you should have had auto-correction for that; if you wrote it from a computer then there is no reason to skip vowels. Vowels are people too. Frankly, it's borderline insulting to read such post written like this. It's fine to complain, it's not fine to make this a forum of 16 year olds who go through the phase of talking in shortcuts.

Comment: Being on the topic of proper English; please write "I", not "i".

Comment: @Asaf, Michael: I don't know, guys, I think correcting someone's spelling can wait until they are in a good mood.

Comment: A search reveals this: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1435/complaints/ It may be relevant

Comment: @rahul Asaf already told that to Mick at the [link](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1435/complaints/) mentioned.

Comment: @Rahul: If I saw a question, or an answer written **that** badly with “ppl” instead of “people” I'd vote to close, delete and generally vote against the said post. If mick wants to be taken seriously he should make the impression that he is trying *at least* to write comprehensible posts, and not internet-abbreviations filled post.

Comment: I write ppl sometimes to save time.
Its not that i like abbreviations that much.

Comment: @mick You save *your time*, not time in general.

Comment: I've never had such bugs - and as said here, no one heard about someone who had this problem. Isn't sit something on your computer?

Comment: A good suggestion: "Ask: "Downvote for no reason?" - quickly someone will come saying: "I think they are downvoting for n reasons..." <-It was him! =)

Comment: mick, I can assure you that *many* of the users on the site have very little free time to spend here, yet they do. In some mysterious way they all write *full English words*. I'm sure you can spend that little extra two seconds typing "people". If you take what you write seriously, others might will as well.

Comment: Trying to save time? It is very hard to believe that you type _ppl_ because you want to save time. QWERTY keyboard _was_ introduced to save time. Text language is frowned upon if you are using a computer. **This is not Facebook or Twitter.**

Comment: At everyone : Im sorry I wrote "ppl". But do not make a fuss about it. Besides I do not think I did it often in those few months. Actually imho I think it makes me look unprofessional and sloppy. Rather than to cause anything bad to others. @DumbCow : I do not know if you realise but we met on chat. I enjoyed your company on chat and I believe it was likewise.
On top of the comments to everyone, I like to say I do not like mixed behaviour if you know what I mean. Besides I do not have QWERTY. Maybe Im overreacting here and the comments are more taken as advice. So I say hi  :) (smiley ok ?)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am sorry that you've had a bad initial experience on MSE. I have never heard of anyone encountering all the problems you describe. I suggest that you try the [math chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics). You can describe what's been happening to you and see if anyone there has had the same experiences, and perhaps someone there might have a suggestion for how to solve whatever has gone wrong in your case.

Comment: @mick m.SE is **really nice** compared to several other much worse (and here unnamed) SE's which I have visited. They (or at least, the single administrator hanging around unilaterally closing all the questions they didn't like) insisted on enforcing their forum rules Soviet Russia style, ensuring that their forum will always remain sleepy and uninviting.

Comment: @rschwieb: while I am glad you like math.SE, this is **not** a forum to bash other SE sites.

Comment: I needed context and I didn't name names, so I think I stayed on point just fine.

Comment: @rschwieb: Refusing to name the SE sites of which you disapprove is far better than naming them; however, it adds little context to the comment. It only means something to those who know which sites are mentioned from your description, and to them, you are bashing those sites. In any case, saying that math.SE is really nice *compared to much worse SE sites* is faint praise.

Comment: These points you are making are peripheral distractions to what I think is a fair point. The point was supposed to be "math.SE is among the most tolerant and inviting SE communities I have visited". This is equivalent (although admittedly less angsty) to what I said. Don't worry though, I probably won't have a second chance to make such a comment in the future, and even then I will think twice because of our exchange.

Comment: @rschwieb: I'm sorry if I came across as uninviting. I am very glad that you like math.SE and welcome any comments you have. Unfortunately, having just dealt with some unhappy comments elsewhere, I was not quite sure where yours were coming from. Please forgive my lack of tact.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of times I've had a problem, not with math.SE but with StackOverflow, in which pages open up with incorrect formatting of headings, menus, etc., apparently due to the CSS for the site getting corrupted in my browser's cache.  So it may be worth emptying your cache if the site format looks weird/unreadable.

Apart from that, I'm sorry you had a bad day.  I know it can take away your enthusiasm for the enterprise much longer than that.

Comment: +1, CTRL+F5 saved my day often enough

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the other stuff, but you're definitely not the only one experiencing technical difficulties at Stack Exchange right now.

For most of today, I've had a red "new message" notification button stuck at the top left of every page, but clicking it just gives *"An error occurred while loading - please try again."* and it won't go away.  Annoying.

I think I might've gotten rid of it, though — it looks like it works here on meta but not on the main site.  Go figure.  But yeah, something is definitely a bit screwy here at Stack Exchange right now.  Hopefully, the devs are working to fix it, whatever it is.

Comment: I had that problem for a while, but it went away after a cache cleanse (deep page reload in my browser).

Comment: Yeah, I solved my problem too, it actually turned out to be my own fault: I had an old experimental user script that I'd forgotten about, and I guess that some recent change made the script start breaking all SE AJAX calls. :( After removing the script, everything works fine again.